# How not to lose data of chrome extension when all instances of the browser are closed

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-storage

I am trying to store a state that is generated in the background.js file for extension related to chrome tabs.

When i close the browser and open it again, that data needs to be there.

Using chrome Storage API does not persist the data once the browser is closed.

Need some workaround that thing.

Comment: Chrome storage persists the data by design so in your case it's either a bug or you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I would need to see your code, should have a 'set' at some point, and 'get' in your background.js.  eg chrome.storage.sync.get.  As wOxxOm mentioned, it does persists, however, are you sure you're using the chrome storage api, and not the Local Storage in the chrome Dev tools.  Because that is not persistent as I recall.

Comment: @wOxxOm - yeah, I was not reading the values correctly. It worked after tinkering it for some time. Thanks for the help

Comment: @JasonOwens. Yes, you are right. It returns values in an asynchronous manner and that's where the problem was. I was not getting the console.logs properly. It's working as expected now. Thanks.